# new created pipenv environment is not empty

Tags: python, ros, pipenv

I created a new env with pipenv shell however doing pip freeze (yes inside the environment)
does return many installed packages.

I tried pipenv clean and pipenv uninstall --all  but same result. The packages (rekated to ROS apparently) but how can I create a new environment without them. Some of the packages:

```
    rqt-robot-dashboard==0.5.7
    rqt-robot-monitor==0.5.13
    rqt-robot-steering==0.5.10
    rqt-runtime-monitor==0.5.7
    rqt-rviz==0.6.0
    rqt-service-caller==0.4.8
    rqt-shell==0.4.9
    rqt-srv==0.4.8
    rqt-tf-tree==0.6.0
    rqt-top==0.4.8
    rqt-topic==0.4.11
    rqt-web==0.4.8
    rviz==1.13.13
    sensor-msgs==1.12.7
    smach==2.0.1
    smach-ros==2.0.1
    smclib==1.8.5
    tf==1.12.1
    tf-conversions==1.12.1
    rosbag==1.14.9
    rosboost-cfg==1.14.9
    rosclean==1.14.9
    roscreate==1.14.9
    rosgraph==1.14.9
    roslaunch==1.14.9
    roslib==1.14.9
    roslint==0.11.2
    roslz4==1.14.9
```

To Summarize:
Doing pip freeze in the global environment shows all packages ROS + others.
Doing pip freeze in the created environment, does not show the "other" packages only the ROS one.How can I create an empty one?

Comment: What is your problem ? You installed some package for the whole system, so they are available everywhere. If you want your package to only be available to a given environment you should have installed all your package in your virtual environments. What is the solution you want us to bring you ?

Comment: The solution I want is i do not want any package in my environment. Creating a new environment should return me 0 packages. How can I create the environment without ROS packages?

Answer (score 1):

I have a bunch of packages installed on my system, but I don't experience the same problem. I think this is because I typically create a Pipfile before doing `pipenv install`.

To test this, I made an empty Pipfile like this:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[dev-packages]

[scripts]

[requires]
python_version="3"

[packages]
```

I then did `pipenv install`, then `pipenv run pip freeze`. This gave no output. I then added one package manually to the Pipfile, did the same again, and this time got the expected output.

This may be replicable by you as follows:

- delete the virtual environment you already created
- make the blank Pipfile in your project as outlined
- do `pipenv install`
- do `pipenv run pip freeze`

(if it doesn't work, maybe add some details about your OS, pipenv version etc.)

Comment: Sadly same result could it be that somehow installation of ROS affects the packages for the environment?

Comment: Could there be any other virtual environments hanging about, corresponding the directory you're working in or its parent directories? Maybe try cleaning up before resorting to uninstalling ROS from the system. That said, searching around suggested maybe ROS doesn't always play nice with others, e.g. https://github.com/ros/ros/issues/149

Comment: So what i noticed is if I remove from my ~/.bashrc file the following ros statement: 
#source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
#source ~/el/ros_tut/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
the ros packages are gone

Comment: So first prob solved however I still have lingering packages:

absl-py==0.10.0
astor==0.8.1
gast==0.2.2
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.32.0
h5py==2.10.0
importlib-metadata==2.0.0
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
Markdown==3.2.2
numpy==1.19.2
opt-einsum==3.3.0
protobuf==3.13.0
six==1.15.0
tensorboard==1.14.0
tensorflow==1.15.0
tensorflow-estimator==1.14.0
tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0
termcolor==1.1.0
Werkzeug==1.0.1
wrapt==1.12.1
zipp==3.2.0